# BottomSheet с эффектом AlertDialog

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Каким образом можно расширить `BottomSheet`, чтобы при его появлении снизу остальная часть экрана темнела и при клике на нее панель задвигалась обратно как в `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно наследоваться от [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html)

```
public class TutsPlusBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

        if( behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior ) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new TutsPlusBottomSheetDialogFragment();
bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
```

[Источник](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)